# Can not use dependency module right away after installing with --save-dev

Tags: node.js, npm

I don't know if this is common. But why I can not use (import or require) dependency modules right away after I installed it with `npm install --save-dev module`?

Yet I have to reinstall it again using `npm install --only=dev` and only after that, I'd be able to require the module.

Is this the normal and the most practical way?

Answer (score 0):

You did it the wrong way around. It's: `npm install <package name> --save-dev`

it can be that if you try to `require()` it through JS, that it says that the `require()` method is undefined. But it'll still work if you test your package out.

Hope this helps

Here is an example on how I require my packages:

`#!/usr/bin/env node`

`var awesomevarname = require('packagename');`